# How to solve $\frac {\partial^3z} { \partial x^3}-\frac{3\partial^3z}{\partial x^2\partial y}+\frac{2 \partial ^3z}{\partial x \partial^2y}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm unable to solve this problem please help me with this problem :$$\frac {\partial^3z} { \partial x^3}-\frac{3\partial^3z}{\partial x^2\partial y}+\frac{2 \partial ^3z}{\partial x \partial^2y}=0$$

Comment: "factor" out $\frac {\partial} {\partial x}$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac {\partial^3z} { \partial x^3}-\frac{3\partial^3z}{\partial x^2\partial y}+\frac{2 \partial ^3z}{\partial x \partial^2y}=0$$
$$m^3-3m^2+2m=0$$
Factorize:
$$m(m^2-3m+2)=0$$
$$m(m-1)(m-2)=0$$
$$\implies S_m=\{0,1,2\}$$
Therefore:
$$z(x,y)=\phi _1 (y)+ \phi_2(y+x)+\phi_3(y+2x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
x^3 - 3 x^2 y + 2 x y^2 = x(x-2y)(x-y)
$$